# Polymer input change event

Tags: javascript, polymer

All I want is to be able to get the input from a polymer element <paper-input> and alert it onchange WITHOUT creating a custom polymer element.

issues:
  on-change doesn't do anything
  I doubt this.value will do anything

Pseudocode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><!--insert proper head elements here--></head>
  <body>
    <paper-input floatingLabel label="test" on-change="alert(this.value)"></paper-input>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if the OP wanted a change callback while typing...but for Polymer 1.0+ one can listen to the changes while typing simply use the `on-input` instead of `on-change` "event"

```
<paper-input label="Enter search term" on-input="search" value="{{searchTerm}}">
```

Answer (score 8):

The `on-*` [declarative event handlers](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) are syntactic sugar provided by Polymer, so `on-change` won't work outside of a Polymer element. You can do the same thing in vanilla Javascript using `querySelector` and `addEventListener`:

```
<paper-input floatingLabel label="test"></paper-input>

<script>
  document.querySelector('paper-input').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [Declarative event handlers](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/events) in Polymer 3 docs.

Answer (score 7):

`<paper-input>` element will fire 'value' property change event (a non-bubbling DOM event when a 'value' property changes)

elements declaration:

```
<paper-input label="Enter search term" 
             on-value-changed="_onSearchTermChanged" 
             value="{{searchTerm}}">
```

event handling:

```
_onSearchTermChanged: function (event) {
     console.log(event.detail.value);
 }
```

For more details check [Polymer's Change Notification Events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#change-events)

Comment: why is this nowhere in paper-inputs docs! It seems like this event would be extremely important and yet i can not find it anywhere in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom change event name in the annotation using the following syntax https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#two-way-native :

```
target-prop="{{hostProp::target-change-event}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with paper-slider and found out that the "on-change" doesn't do anything, but "onchange" triggered what I wanted. Since paper-input is a Polymer element, it should work with the declarative event handling.

Comment: onchange="" is an old way of handling and overriding javascript events.  addEventListener in the answer above is correct.  Also, on-change="" is not the same as onchange="".  The reason why the original on-change listed above wasn't working is because you need to give it something like: on-change="{{myTestClick}}" and in the code do myTestClick: function (event, detail, sender) { alert('hi'); }  They are meant to be used from within the implementation of your element.  Not outside.