# Polymer paper-input on-change doesn't trigger on firefox 33.0.3

Tags: html, firefox, input, onchange, polymer

I am trying to run the tutorial example given at http://itshackademic.com/static/codelabs/3-polymer-build-mobile/. The final code works fine, on Chrome. However, on firefox 33.0.3 the `<paper-input on-change="{{add}}"/>` doesn't call the appropriate function. The code is below, and as I mentioned pressing "Return" while on paper-input doesn't trigger the function. I checked a couple similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940775/polymer-input-change-event) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160493/polymer-paper-input-and-form-submission)), but the solutions there don't really apply.

The code works fine on Chrome just fine.
Any suggestions?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>PolymerMobileCodelab</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="codelab-app.html">
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <codelab-app></codelab-app>
</body>
</html>
```

codelab-app.html:

```
<!-- New polymer element -->

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">

<polymer-element name="codelab-app">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsiveWidth="641px">

      <core-header-panel drawer>
      <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>
      </core-header-panel>

      <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button  icon="menu" core-drawer-toggle>

          </paper-icon-button>
          <span flex>My notes</span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>

          <paper-fab icon="icons:add" on-click="{{showNewNoteInput}}"></paper-fab>
        </core-toolbar>

        <div class="content">
          <paper-input  id="newNoteInput"
                        floatingLabel
                        on-change="{{add}}"
                        value="{{newNote}}"
                        label="Add a new note"></paper-input>
          <template repeat="{{data}}" >
            <div center horizontal layout class="item">
              <paper-checkbox checked="{{done}}" on-change="{{dataChanged}}"></paper-checkbox>
              <div flex class="card">
                <p>{{body}}</p>
              </div>
              <!-- paper-icon-button icon="clear" on-click="{{remove}}"></paper-icon-button -->
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>

      </core-header-panel>

    </core-drawer-panel>
    <core-localstorage id="storage" name="codelab-app-storage" value="{{data}}"></core-localstorage>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      data: [],
      ready: function() {
        this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'none';
      },
      showNewNoteInput: function() {
        this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'block';
      },

      add: function() {
        if (this.newNote) {
          this.data.unshift({
            body: this.newNote,
            done: false
          });
          this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'none';
          this.$.newNoteInput.value = null;
        }
      },
      remove: function() {

      },
      dataChanged: function() {
        this.$.storage.save();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/diwapu/4/edit) version of your code.

This is likely related to some of the refactoring that was done with `<paper-input>` around the time of the Polymer 0.5 release. I opened a bug at https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/111 that you can follow along with.

Comment: Thanks - I saw your open ticket there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue from the Polymer side. It was resolved as of [current version](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/111).

`change()` action was declared in the paper-input.html, and had a conditional execution and prevented firing on old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the paper-input and use the attributenameChanged callback on it's prototype. pass it around with an "app-global" element of sorts if you need.
but yes, i guess it shouldn't be like this.

i'm going to try and reproduce/fix/hack it and get back.